# Is there a way to detect 404 pages using HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am parsing a forum where some threads are already deleted. So opening them still shows a page but with a message that says "Thread no longer exists". Is there a way to query this using the HtmlAgilityPack in a special way?

Or do I have to compare the InnerHtml or something along those lines?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing what you are going to parse

Comment: Why not write it your self..Get all links on page and recursively ping.

Comment: 404 is not a page, it's a protocol status code.

Comment: can you post an example link to a forum post that is removed?

Comment: Well I am storing the links but not opening the page until the user clicks it. Then the user sees if the thread is deleted or not. An example of a deleted thread looks like this: http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=154833803

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a 404 is not actually being returned.  If it was, you could just look at the headers.

That said, you are getting a 200 response with an error in the html, therefore you will have to parse the html, traverse the DOM, whatever you want to call it and determine if it failed.

It appears that there could potentially be several different error messages, so I would try to make your comparison generic by looking for the "notify administrator" link or perhaps the class="blockrow restore" is only used on the error page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, is 200 reserved for errors? Can I just use that? I actually already implemented this using the InnerText and querying if that text exists, and it works. Just thought there might be an error code HtmlAP would receive or something.

Comment: nah, 200 is success.  200 OK --- from Wikipedia ---
Standard response for successful HTTP requests. The actual response will depend on the request method used. In a GET request, the response will contain an entity corresponding to the requested resource. In a POST request the response will contain an entity describing or containing the result of the action.[2]